# show the window print dialog using JavaScript in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing

I’m using JavaScrpt window.print() function to print out the document. But here is a problem in Google Chrome when window.print() function is run it shows the Chrome print dialog not window print dialog. How can I show the window print dialog in Google Chrome?

Comment: What is the difference between ` Chrome print dialog`  and `window print dialog` ?? `window.print()` opens the Print Dialog Box of browser that's it.

Comment: Open this Link in Chrome and see the result - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_print

Comment: @prog there are differences, the system print dialog is the one that most apps show, that allows to finetune all printer parameters. Google Print Dialog is a simplified dialog.

Comment: Uhm, no there's no difference, calling `window.print()` opens the browsers default print window, just like hitting CTRL-P does.

Answer (score 0):

afaik this is the only way to tell the browser to show the print dialog. Unfortunately Google Chrome decides to show its own dialog and there's little you can do about it from the programmer's side. The user can show the system dialog pressing "Print Using System Dialog".